# How can I get the figure number in subfigure without common caption?

Tags: includegraphics

How can I get "Figure 2a)" , "Figure 2b)" instead of just "a)" and "b)" ? I don't want to have a caption for both, just like this , only with the number in front of a) and b). [image: subfigure]

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Figures/Fig13.22a_layer_structure.png}
    \caption{Layer structure of CIGS solar cell. The \textit{pn}-junction is also referred to as a \textit{buried junction}, because the separation of electron-hole pairs happens one layer above. Image source: \cite[p.193]{smets-2016}}
    \label{fig:CIGS-layer-structure}
  \end{subfigure}
\hspace{1cm}
\centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Figures/Fig13.22b_band_diagram.png}
    \caption{Band diagram of CIGS solar cell. Image source: \cite[p.193]{smets-2016}}
    \label{fig:CIGS-band-diagram}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with a combination of [`subcaption`](//ctan.org/pkg/subcaption)'s `\subref` and a redefinition of the `labelformat` for the `sub`type:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\thefigure\alph{subfigure})}
\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=simple}

\begin{document}

See Figure~\subref{fig:example-image-a}.

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{First figure}
    \label{fig:example-image-a}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hspace{1cm}%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Second figure}
    \label{fig:example-image-b}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! How can I get the reference to be only "3a" instead of "3a)" ? Or would you always include the bracket? I am just asking, because at one point I have it in brackets, so it looks a bit weird: "(see Figure 3a))."

Comment: @AskingBecauseIHaveQuestions: That seems like an edge case that you can manage manually. See [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/NNHp3BKU) for a possible solution.

Comment: @AskingBecauseIHaveQuestions Drop the closing brace inside `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{...}` and replace `labelformat=simple` with `labelformat=brace`.

Comment: Thanks! But I thought about it and I think it is more correct to have a double bracket then..